# addition within sum case when

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

How to sum all the customers in DS01,02,03 into DS?
[image]

select
sum(case when Ticket='DS01' OR 'DSO2' OR 'DS03' THEN customer ELSE 0 END) AS DS
sum(case when Ticket='MSO2' OR 'MS03' THEN customer ELSE 0 END) AS MS
from table
group by ticket
unsure how to bring in addition condition within "THEN and ELSE " part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left()`:

```
select left(ticket, 2), sum(customers)
from t
group by left(ticket, 2);
```

Or, if you want explicit lists:

```
select (case when ticket in ('DS01', 'DS02', 'DS03') then 'DS'
             when ticket in ('MS02', 'MS03') then 'MS'
        end), sum(customers)
from t
group by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. The table is long with some more mix of alphabets and numbers
inputting them inside case statement only works. case when Ticket='DS01' OR 'DSO2' OR 'DS03' THEN customer ELSE 0 END
Hence looking for a solution that will have case when then